# Is there any-way to count the total number of topological sort in a DAG without finding the all possible order?

Tags: algorithm, graph, topological-sort

Suppose this is a question.....

[image]

How can I calculate total number of the topological sort without finding all orders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general this is
[#P-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extension). This
particular graph happens to be
[series–parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series%E2%80%93parallel_graph),
however, which makes it easy. Graphs in series cause the number of
possibilities for each graph to be multiplied. For the particular graph
you show, there are three diamonds in series, each of which has two
valid extensions, so there are eight possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

[Check the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCjZs.jpg)

For each of the rectangles **[u,v]** either **u** can appear **first** or **v** can appear **first** 
So for these pairs **[a,b], [c,d], [e,f]**, we have two choices.
And for the remaining elements p, q, r, s, they have only one choice because
we have to **start with p and end with s** 
p ->(a or b)-> q -> (c or d) -> r -> (e or f) -> s. 
Total = 1 * 2 * 1 * 2 * 1 * 2 * 1 = 8
Hence total of 8 topological ordering is possible.